# Minor Flaw with this Jave code

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the code to print out a whole song of 99 bottles of beer on the wall. I got it from a book. I'm just starting out. The code is alright and runs fine. There's just one minor hiccup. When it gets down to 1 bottle, it says "bottles" the first time. The if statement didn't seem to take effect on that line or something. My question is: what's causing it to be plural in the first 1 line?

```
public class bottle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int beerNum = 99;
        String word = "bottles";

        while (beerNum > 0) {

            if (beerNum == 1) {
                word = "bottle";
            }

            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall");
            System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer");
            System.out.println("Take one down.");
            System.out.println("Pass it around.");
            beerNum = beerNum - 1;

            if (beerNum > 0) {
                System.out.println(beerNum + " " + word + " of beer on the wall.");
            } else {
                System.out.println("No more bottles of beer on the wall.");
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Closed before I could post an answer, but essentially `beerNum` is being checked *before* it's decreased, so `1` is printed when `beerNum == 1` is false, because `beerNum` was `2`.  It's rather clear to me what's being asked here, and I have an answer I can post, voting to re-open.

Comment: Think of the value of beerNum when it reaches 1. It will enter the second if-block before the final turn, and word will still be bottles.

Comment: Consider this two questions: where is `beerNum` updated? when is `word` updated? Follow the logic, and you'll find what's happening

Comment: Thanks guys! Appreciate the feedback. Sorry the site took my question offline before you could actually answer. I got my answer now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You subtract one from `beerNum` in the middle of the loop.

`word` isn't set until the start of the *next* loop.

More explicit help (e.g., spoiler; don't roll over until you've thought about it):

> Move the count check further down into the loop.
>  
>  E.g., after the first bunch of statements, but before the last line of the verse.

Comment: So, should I move the if statement below the subtract 1 line?

Yeah. I wrote that before I saw your last two lines in the spoiler box lol

Comment: I moved that block and it fixed the flaw. It's funny because I got it from a textbook and that's how they wrote it. They obviously didn't run it before....I just now remembered while typing this comment, the book did mention there would be a flaw and to find it. If I would have remembered that, I would have tried harder to fix it myself. Thanks though lol